# executeAsync Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

I am calling the request.executeAnsyc to fill my array with information and display on listview. Sadly the array is called before the request.executeAnsyc is finished .. so nothing is displayed onCreatView method of my Fragment.

Is there a way to use the array after the request.executeAnsyc finished and to display the info on the listview?!

Best Regards.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kizombalistfestival,
            container, false);
    listUsersInformation = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            new Request(session, "/me", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                            /* handle the result */

                            String serverresponse = response
                                    .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject()
                                    .toString();
                            Log.e("serverresponse", "" + serverresponse);
                            JSONObject jsonobj;

                            try {

                                jsonobj = new JSONObject(serverresponse);
                                UserInfo temp = new UserInfo(jsonobj
                                        .getString("id"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("first_name"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("gender"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("last_name"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("link"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("locale"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("name"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("timezone"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("updated_time"), jsonobj
                                        .getString("verified"));

                                listUsersInformation.add(temp);




                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }).executeAsync();




        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_festivals);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<UserInfo>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listUsersInformation));



    return rootView;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to implement this.

**1. using Handler to update your listview in finally block**

```
new Request(session, "/me", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        /* handle the result */

                        String serverresponse = response
                                .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject()
                                .toString();
                        Log.e("serverresponse", "" + serverresponse);
                        JSONObject jsonobj;

                        try {

                            jsonobj = new JSONObject(serverresponse);
                            UserInfo temp = new UserInfo(jsonobj
                                    .getString("id"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("first_name"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("gender"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("last_name"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("link"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("locale"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("name"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("timezone"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("updated_time"), jsonobj
                                    .getString("verified"));

                            listUsersInformation.add(temp);




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            // add your code here
                            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                       list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_festivals);
                                   list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<UserInfo>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listUsersInformation));
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

**2. using broadcast receiver**

First, you should register your receiver in the fragment you'd like to update your listview. Then, in your Facebook function class, sendBroadcast(intent) to your registered fragment, just like below:

```
// your fb request callback
try {

    jsonobj = new JSONObject(serverresponse);
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("first_name", first_name);
    intent.putExtra("gender", gender);
    intent.putExtra("last_name", last_name);
    // ... and so on  
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Eventually, in your fragment which registered broadcastreceiver,

```
private final BroadcastReceiver streamReceiver = new    BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        ///Waking up mobile of it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String id = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
        String first_name = intent.getExtras().getString("first_name");     
        String gender = intent.getExtras().getInt("gender");
        ...
        ...
        UserInfo temp = new UserInfo(id, 
                                     first_name,
                                     gender, .....);

        listUsersInformation.add(temp);            

        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```